# Is there a Finder extension to rate individual files and folders with stars?

Tags: mac, finder

iTunes allows us to rate music and iPhoto allows to rate photos but I've not seen a general Finder extension/feature to rate ANY file or folder with stars and be able to sort by that rating.

Isn't it possible or does no one else ever thought of such feature? I can't find any extension or plugin that adds this ability.

In best case it would adopt the stars already defined in the named apps so that a change there is equally reflected in Finder views.

Comment: ...maybe OSX Lion adds something here...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Tagit](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/30228/tagit). That should fulfill what you need.

Comment: It's not too bad... but it doesn't integrate with finder. Even the released sequel named "Leap" doesn't integrate - although it simulates a similar interface. So it's an option... but not exactly what I'm looking for.